# I can't assign element fields in map method

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting the following error:

> *Argument of type `'(item: ItemType) => void'` is not assignable too parameter.*

I can't seem to understand what's going on.

```
type MainProps = {
  book: Array<Object>;
  setFirstAction: (found: Array<Object>) => Array<Object>;
}
            
type ItemType = {
  volumeInfo: Object;
}
            
class Main extends Component<MainProps, {}> {
  render() {
    const { book } = this.props
    const books = book?.map((item: ItemType) => {
      //right here
      console.log(item.volumeInfo);
    })
    // console.log(book)

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: is it because the `map` function expects a return value?

Comment: TL;DR: `book: Array<ItemType>;` as `Object` do not have a `volumeInfo` property.

Comment: I can't define item in map method. it works if I change it to item: any, but i want to item:Array<Object> and it doesn't work. It has to be typed

Comment: @dinis when you type `book: Array<Object>`, it tells typescript that the items are `Object`. Then, `ItemType` can't be used to type the items when looping since it's incompatible with the `Object` type.